# Is there a log to see when a user is trying to access file/directory that he doesn't have permission?

Tags: mysql, centos, redhat, mysql-replication

My database is failing to replicate and the only clue in the error log is `Operation Not Permitted`, which I am guessing is file access permission failure either on donar or joiner. Is there any file that I could `tail` to see what exactly files does the user/process is trying read/write/execute?

Comment: tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log what error it is logging?

Comment: It fails with `130521  6:59:31 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (7ff38373-c1d1-11e2-0800-d595d1800e6a): 1 (Operation not permitted)`

Answer (score 1):

The `auditd(8)` daemon provides the functionality you request in your question. It is configured in the `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` file, and its syntax is described in the `auditd.conf(5)` manual page.

You need to install and enable the daemon, and configure the `/etc/audit/audit.rules` to audit those events you consider relevant. And example from the `audit.rules(7)` manpage:

```
   -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open -S openat -F exit=-EACCES -k access
   -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open -S openat -F exit=-EPERM -k access
   -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open -S openat -F exit=-EACCES -k access
   -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open -S openat -F exit=-EPERM -k access
```

Read the `auditctl(8)` manpage for an explanation of all the options used in the examples.

For later analysis/reporting, you can use the `ausearch(8)` and `aureport(8)` tools.